# { ProcessName, NodeName } ! Message VS rpc:call/4 VS HTTP/1.1 across Erlang Nodes

Tags: http, unix, erlang, chat, messaging

I have a setup in which two nodes are going to be communicating a lot. On Node A, there are going to be thousands of processes, which are meant to access services on Node B. There is going to be a massive load of requests and responses across the two nodes. The two Nodes, will be running on two different servers, each on its own hardware server.

I have 3 Options: HTTP/1.1 , rpc:call/4 and Directly sending a message to a registered gen_server on Node B. Let me explain each option.
**HTTP/1.1**
 Suppose that on Node A, i have an HTTP Client like `Ibrowse`, and on Node B, i have a web server like `Yaws-1.95`, the web server being able to handle unlimited connections, the operating system settings tweaked to allow yaws to handle all connections. And then make my processes on Node A to communicate using HTTP. In this case each method call, would mean a single HTTP request and a reply. I believe there is an overhead here, but we are evaluating options here. The erlang Built in mechanism called `webtool`, may be built for this kind of purpose.

 **rpc:call/4**
 I could simply make direct rpc calls from Node A to Node B. I am not very susre how the underlying rpc mechanism works , but i think that when two erlang nodes connect via `net_adm:ping/1`, the created connection is not closed but all rpc calls use this pipe to transmit requests and pass responses. Please correct me on this one.
**Sending a Message from Node A to Node B** 
 I could make my processes on Node A to just send message to a registered process, or a group of processes on Node B. This too seems a clean option.

**Q1.** Which of the above options would you recommend and why, for an application in which two erlang nodes are going to have enormous communications between them all the time. Imagine a messaging system, in which two erlang nodes are the routers :) ?
 **Q2.** Which of the above methods is cleaner, less problematic and is more fault tolerant (i mean here that, the method should NOT have single point of failure, that could lead to all processes on Node A blind) ? 
**Q3.** The mechanism of your choice: how would you make it even more fault tolerant, or redundant? 
 **Assumptions:**  The Nodes are always alive and will never go down, the network connection between the nodes will always be available and non-congested (dedicated to the two nodes only) , the operating system have allocated maximum resources to these two nodes.
 Thank you for your evaluations

Comment: I've asked a similar question before. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12508539/erlang-remote-call-vs-sending-messages And I don't think it is a good idea to use http when there is some solution provided by the language itself. HTTP api may be less efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q1: HTTP will add additional overhead and will give you nothing in my opinion. HTTP would be useful if you were designing a REST API. Directly sending messages and rpc:call look about the same as far as overhead is regarded.

Q2: Sending messages is much much clearer. It's the way erlang is designed. With RPC calls you must always track which call is executed where and under which circumstances which can be a huge issue if the two servers have state. Also RPC calls are synchronous.

Q3: I would use UBF if I can afford minor overhead, otherwise I would directly send messages between the erlang nodes. If the bandwidth is an issue other trickery would be needed as well. Like encoding the messages in same way and then using some compression algorithm to reduce the size of the message, alternatively I may ditch the erlang message passing altogether and use UDP sockets.

Answer (score 3):

HTTP is definitely out. Just the round-trip overhead of creating a new connection is a problem.

As for Erlang connections and using Pids, you have the advantage that you can subscribe to node-down messages and handle the case where a node goes down. A single TCP connection should be able to give you very fast speeds, however, be aware that it works like a long pipe: messages are muxed and demuxed on a pipe which can affect latency on the line. It also means that large messages will block small messages from getting through.

How much bandwidth are you aiming for, and at what latency? What is the 95th and 99th percentile of answering messages? It is better to put up some rough numbers and then try to target these than just having "as fast as possible". Set your success criteria first.

Answer (score 1):

It is not obvious that ! is the best way to go. Definitely, it is the easiest and the code will be the most elegant.

In terms of scalability, take under consideration that to use rpc/! you have to maintain an erlang cluster. I found it painful having just 10-20 nodes even in private cloud. I would never recommend bigger deployments on e.g. EC2, where io/latency/network is not deterministic.

I recommend to structure the project in a way that will let you exchange communication engine in the future. Also HTTP is pretty heavy, but there are options:

- socket-socket (tcp/udp/sctp)
- amqp (many benefits connected to load balancing)
- zeromq (even nicer than amqp)

Betting on !/rpc and OTP cluster is risky. You will fight with full mesh overhead, master election algos and quorum/partition detection.

Comment: np, ..and don't get me wrong. It is easy to have 100+ nodes cluster. It just does not for free.